# Mutual and Non Mutual events.

Tags: probability

An integer is chosen at random from the first 50 integers. A is the event 'divisible by 2', B is the event divisible by 3, C is the event divisible by 5. Find P(A and B)

Can someone please help direct me on how to find A,B and C I think I can do the rest.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm assuming that first 50 integers means your randomly chosen number is between 1 and 50.

Now, you have 50 possibilities, and 25 of those are even right? So $P(A)=(25/50)=0.5$.
P(B) and P(C) can be found with the same reasoning.

Comment: is B=16/50 and C= 10/50?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: thanks!, ill ask more if I have trouble with the rest

Answer (score 1):

Event A=Number of values that are divisible by 2 within the range of 0 and 50 = 25.
implies P(A)=25/50=0.5.
Event B=Number of values that are divisible by 3 within the range of 0 and 50 = 16.
implies P(B)=16/50=0.32
Event C=Number of values that are divisible by 5 within the range of 0 and 50 = 10.
implies P(C)=10/50=0.2

*(P(x) is probability of that Event x to occur).